# How to add dynamic link at line level?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am trying to add HTML link at line level of transaction records. Please let me know how we can add the link.

I created one column Inline HTML field on line level of Sales Order and tried to save the link on it. But Netsuite Throwing error "Can not set more than 15 Characters".

Comment: You would generally use a field of type hyperlink for that and not a field of type inline html. Sounds like you set a maximum length for the inline html field and are trying to put more than that in it.

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to add the link. Can you share you code? 
From the error it seems you are trying to add the link on the field.linkText.

field.linkText represents the Hyperlink text. 
Then you need to setup the URL like in any other field.

Example:

Using URL field on a serverWidget field.

```
//Create field. You can always use a standard one
    objItemSublist.addField({
                id : 'custpage_test',
                type : serverWidget.FieldType.URL,
                label : 'Label'
             }).linkText = 'Click Here';

//Set URL
      objRecord.setSublistValue({
                     sublistId:'item',
                     fieldId:'custpage_test',
                     line:i,
                     value: 'https://stackoverflow.com'
            });
```